# %d expecting int* in c

Tags: c

As per what I know, %d expects an int value. I don't understand why gcc compiler is saying that it expects int* instead.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    int rn, m[5];
    char nm[25];
};

int main()
{
    struct student* s[5];
    struct student **q=s;

    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter data");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\nStudent %d:\n",i+1);
        printf("Roll number: ");
        scanf("%d",(s[i])->rn);
        printf("\n%d",s[i]->rn);
    }
}
```

And here is the warning:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
scanf("%d",(s[i])->rn);
```

Comment: `scanf` expects a pointer so it can actually _change_ the value of the int.

Comment: Also `s[i]` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scanf reads a value into an int, it takes an pointer to the variable to read into.

```
scanf("%d",&((s[i])->rn));
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` takes an `int` for `%d`, but `scanf` takes the address of an `int` (an `int *`) so it can store the converted value.

Answer (score 0):

RTFM would help here. `scanf` and related functions (`sscanf` etc) always need pointers of the variable(s) to which they'll read the values to. [scanf documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)